# How to find client source IP address from a service running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

This can possibly be aa duplicate for [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/813298/how-to-get-the-true-client-ip-for-a-service-running-inside-docker/962926) on serverfault.

However I still couldn't find a working answer!

I'm using docker desktop on wsl2 on windows and apparently the host network mode doesn't work here, accoring to [this page](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Apparently when running any containers inside docker using default configurations, all clients connecting to forwarded ports has the same IP address (Apprarently that of a docker network driver)

So what's the corret way to run a docker container where client IP address can be exposed to the service in the container?